# Is it possible to change display property of div every time page opens

Tags: javascript

Is is possible to do change display: block; to none; with javascript. I would like to show 2 of them everytime page opens. But I want it to be random and change everytime page opens.

Anybody can help me with this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/WcxdR/1/

Comment: Use the [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below one will hide two of them randomly each time. You could reuse this to show only two instead.

```
window.onload = function() {  
  var ran = Math.round(Math.random() * 6);
  document.getElementById("" + ran).style.display = 'none';
  ran = Math.round(Math.random() * 6);
  document.getElementById("" + ran).style.display = 'none';
};
```

P.S: From top of my head. Not tested.
P.S: Will need to put a check if both call to random gives same number

Comment: What if the two numbers are the same? (Also, numerical IDs aren't valid until HTML5, just thought I'd mention that.)

Comment: we don't support HTML4 anymore ;)

Comment: "We" as in SO? And making it a string number isn't really the "invalid" part (unless there is some other reason to do that), I was referring to the way the OP's markup was written.

Comment: @JaredFarrish your solution is the best. I make a little changes to show what Extelliqent [want](http://jsfiddle.net/Galled/RbP2f/3/).

Comment: It was worrying me that the `while` loop may be a problem, so I set a limit on the number of loops and also fixed the random number (so it wouldn't return 0 or 7). A `for` loop would be cleaner, I suppose, but I'm being lazy. http://jsfiddle.net/RbP2f/4/

Answer (score 1):

First the `id` of your form elements always has to [begin with a letter](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name), something like this:

```
<div id="i1">Line 1</div>
```

Then you can access to the `style` properties in this way:

```
document.getElementById("i1").style.display
```

As explained in this [link](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript#Changing_Element_Styles).

Try with this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Galled/WcxdR/4/).

**EDIT:**

What you want is [simple](http://jsfiddle.net/Galled/WcxdR/7/), review the links that I have write for you for more info.

**EDIT2:**

Jared Farrish has made a better solution that my in the comments of the anwser of Suraj Chandran, only to emphasize that what we really need is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Galled/RbP2f/7/) and using [some function](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3724571/Using-Multiple-JavaScript-Onload-Functions.htm) to load multiples function on body-onload event.

And I think he is right in what he says.

Comment: I don`t want to make it display none and block. All I want it when page opens 2 of them appears and every onload page it shows 2 different ones.

Comment: @Extelliqent - Galled is trying to show you how you could select the elements and change them. It shouldn't be that difficult to find a random number script and couple that with `window.onload` to get your effect.

Comment: @Jared Farrish first I`m not really good at javascript, second I don`t wanna select and change their css all I want is every time onload to show 2 different ones it should be something simple

Comment: @Extelliqent - So you really wanted someone to just to write it for you?

Comment: @Extelliqent I updated my anwser, but I highly recommend to you review more tutos of javascript.

Comment: @Galled Thank you very much. I know php a lot and I understand what you wrote clearly and its functions. If I play wit hit for awhile I can make it work I guess

@Jared; First of all that is not your business, second I am not asking for something complicated and time consuming. If you know javascript pretty well you can write it in less then 2-3 minutes. In the end we help each other here in any ways without expecting to pay or do anything. If money is most important with you then rob a bank and move to island so you can live with it together.

Comment: @Extelliqent - Money? Right. *Try* to work it out first. As Galled points out, it's not that hard, and if you know PHP as you say you do, you could have first made an effort. See my last comment on Suraj's answer for how I would do it.

Comment: @Extelliqent - Note as well if you're needing multiple `window.onload` handlers, you should try a framework like jQuery, which could simplify how you code this type of functionality. Although, learning the base way is also useful.

Comment: okay the thing what you don`t understand is this. 1-) I need urgent help. 2-) I need to take javascript class for a week or so to learn it. You can give me simple javascript code which is doing what I need  by spending maximum 10 minutes on it I can write php/css/html5 for you at anytime. This is life Jared, everything is not money. what I want is pretty simple and it won`t take your 5 minutes. if I were to do it, it would take a lot more time for me to learn it from stretch. Why can`t you understand today you help me tomorrow I will help you ? Nobody likes selfish people and don`t be one ;)

Comment: @Galled by the way "http://jsfiddle.net/Galled/RbP2f/3/" this is not working properly. It gives sometimes 1 entry sometimes 2 entry which is not I wanted. Thank you guys really !!